# How to make a new list to point somewhere else, Lisp

Tags: list, pointers, memory, lisp, memory-address

The title is self-explanatory. How can I build a new list X from another list Y (same structure), but the resulting list pointing somewhere else in memory area, practically, another object?  I tried with `make-list :initial-element Y` or appending to an empty list, but I still get the same object. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

**Common Lisp**

Use **COPY-LIST** to copy the first list level.

Use **COPY-TREE** to copy a tree of conses, a multi-level list will be copied on all levels.

Both COPY-TREE and COPY-LIST will only copy the conses and nothing else. The things in the list stay the same (meaning EQL, not EQ).

See the Common Lisp HyperSpec's [The Conses Dictionary](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/c_conses.htm) for these and related functions.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably wanting to use COPY-LIST.

Comment: Yes, this is it. If I setf a place in the new list, the first one won't get changed. Thanks.

Comment: In fact, the problem remains if I use a list-in-list. For instance, given a as '((1 2 3) (4 5 6)) and b as a copy of a, then setf (nth 0 (nth 0 b)) "4" will change both lists.

Comment: Pay attention to the comment that's upvoted the most, and/or read the HyperSpec.  COPY-LIST only copies a *list* - it creates fresh conses for the top-level and then just points to the old data (which, if the old data is a pointer, like another cons, will be shared between the two lists).  COPY-TREE will recurse through your structure and create fresh conses at all levels, but other types of complex data structures may still be shared.  To do this *completely* you have to write your own function, as there is no such thing as a generic copy function.

Answer (score 0):

My copy-list (using sbcl) worked.

REPL:

```
(defvar a '((1 2 3) (4 5 6)))

(defvar b (copy-tree a))

(setf (nth 0 (nth 0 b)) "4")

a

; ((1 2 3) (4 5 6)) is returned

b

;(("4" 2 3) (4 5 6)) is returned
```

Maybe if you gave us more source we could help.